# Way to find out remote user login time on window machine

Tags: java, spring, spring-security-kerberos

I have a requirement which requires a user login time at the windows machine,which I am supposed to capture once the user starts the application. FYI we are using SSO and the server side application is written in java and client is react js. 
Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: The forum can help you, once show what and where you are facing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer have to get the lastloginTime on AD side.